# PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL error: internal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ssl, thin

When working on my app locally using thin and ssl (`thin start --ssl`), I randomly get this error message every 5/10 requests.

```
PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL error: internal error
```

Usually I relaunch the query and it goes well, but it is a pain to having to refresh and being constantly interupted by this not understandable bug.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL error: internal error
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3.6ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL error: internal error
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1:
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:285:in `rescue in log'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1262:in `select'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `block in select_all'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:75:in `cache_sql'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `select_all'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/explain.rb:34:in `logging_query_plan'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
  bullet (4.9.0) lib/bullet/active_record3x.rb:10:in `to_a'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:381:in `find_first'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in `first'
  orm_adapter (0.5.0) lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:17:in `get'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:208:in `serialize_from_session'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise.rb:462:in `block (2 levels) in configure_warden!'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:34:in `fetch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:212:in `user'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:318:in `_perform_authentication'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:104:in `authenticate'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:58:in `current_copasser'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:54:in `copasser_signed_in?'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:62:in `init_current_user'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__685085315745422875__process_action__3032562076037965401__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
  bullet (4.9.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2485068248532510814__call__1362848814740728564__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:18:in `call'
  config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:7:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  font_assets (0.1.11) lib/font_assets/middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  rack-ssl (1.3.4) lib/rack/ssl.rb:27:in `call'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/runner.rb:199:in `run_command'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/runner.rb:155:in `run!'
  thin (1.6.2) bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
   () home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
   () home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
   () home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:0:in `<main>'
```

I found this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10917) but it still remains unsolved.

Any clue on what I should do?

Thanks god it doesn't happen in production, not even in staging, only locally.

I'm using:

```
thin --version
thin 1.6.2 codename Doc Brown
rails --version
Rails 3.2.18
ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-linux]
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.13
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had a similar problem. Look [Stack 33112155](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112155/pgconnectionbad-pqconsumeinput-ssl-error-key-values-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem for a few weeks now, today out of a hunch I added a `pool: 1` in to the relevant section of my `config/database.yml` and now the error seems to have gone away.

Basically were are asking rails to not do connection pooling I in this case.

`development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: ec2-54-83-14-68.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  username: rxeabczdnbhabc
  password: hiddenZFYd1Mv-abEE9jhidden
  database: d93f8pheuqtni3
  pool: 1`